# IHttpClientFactory example implementation without relying on Microsoft.Extensions.Http implementation

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

What's the right way to implement `IHttpClientFactory` without using the default implementation in the `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` package. The built-in implementation only works as an injectable dependency and sometimes I don't need any sort of dependency injection just to make the system simple. I have searched the github repository but I couldn't find the source code.

The interface comes with a single method `CreateClient` which has a single parameter `name`. The issue is that what happens if the developer registers multiple clients for the same URL using different names? I guess that even the default implementation does not address that problem and it creates one `HttpClient` per key and reuses that under the hood. That's why I am looking for an example implementation just to make how exactly it works and just in case I would need to customize the default behavior.

Comment: _" multiple clients for the same URL using different names"_ ... _"does not address that problem"_ - it's not a problem. Why would it address that?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar: Reusing the underlying socket to prevent port exhaustion

Comment: You misunderstood the issue with `HttpClient` then. `HttpClient` uses a `HttpMessageHandler` internally, and if you just do `var myClient = new HttpClient();` it will create a new one. It was having billions of these that exhausted ports. `IHttpClientFactory` maintains a pool of handlers instead to prevent this.

Comment: I recommend reading [You're (probably still) using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://josef.codes/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/)

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar: I need to see it's implementation, do you know where I can find the source code?

Comment: Probably somewhere [in this repository](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/382490be3b3f59777dec9d5594487bf251096a7f/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs).